# Fixing crack in wall & baseboard

Tags: drywall, baseboard, cracks

Based in the UK, 1920's house that needs a bit of work. Last decorated about 10 years ago.

We have a number of cracks in the paintwork that I know how to fix, but here we have a crack in the wall right by the wooden base, and one crack where there is a join in the wood. What is the best way to repair this?

Looking for something like how to fill and paint it to make it look good. If it really needs a bigger replacement job I'd like to know but it's not something we can do immediately so would like to do a "decent" job of making it look better until then,

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We have to assume that there's seasonal movement in the foundation that keeps these cracks alive. Therefore the best approach might be a flexible crack filler, such as painter's caulk (acrylic latex with silicone).

1. Scrape away all loose paint with a putty knife
2. Use a tool to gently groove the crack to remove loose material can create a cavity for caulk
3. Using a fine caulk tip, fill the cracks and tool it flat with a putty knife or similar
4. Allow to dry and repeat if shrinkage is substantial
5. Prime and paint

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sounds good. Is that suitable for both the cracks in the plasterwork and in the wood?

Comment: Yes. Painter's caulk works on about any interior repairs.